# django model inheritance & FK, could not create unique index

Tags: django, inheritance, foreign-keys, polymorphism, unique-index

I want to be able to have a foreign key to a parent class, thereby allowing queries of the children classes as well. All other solutions are nightmarish.
I have tried to make this (Destination is also a parent class that has a # of children classes I want to relate to):

```
class Destination(PolymorphicModel)

class Account(Destination)

class Organization(Destination)

class Person(Destination)

class Transaction(models.Model)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, verbose_name="Destination", null=True, blank=True,
                                related_name="CompletedTransaction_Destination_FK")
```

I am referencing destination in other places as well.
This is the error message I get when I try to migrate:

psycopg2.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "baseapp_organization_organization_destination_ptr_id_key"
DETAIL: Key (organization_destination_ptr_id)=(1) is duplicated.

I would love it if I could make the destination class

```
abstract = True
```

but then I can't have a foreign key. I need to be able to choose all of those destinations, and they need to remain distinct, real models in the database.

I have also tried GenericRelations, but that proved to be a nightmare as I said earlier.

It feels like I could just get around this error somehow though, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, and I'm guessing it would apply to other errors where the index could not be created, was to wipe the database an delete all the migrations. It was a pain to be sure, but now I can do:

```
destinations = Destination.objects.all()
```

and it will give me all the objects, as according to [django polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)